# C++23 changes disallow using dynamically allocated array as storage provider?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-lawyer, placement-new

This is a basic example of using a dynamic unsigned char array as a ["storage"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.object#3) for a type T.

```
unsigned char* storage = new unsigned char[sizeof(T)];
T* foo = new(storage) T; // line 2
// use *foo somehow
foo->~T(); //destroy our foo

delete[] storage; // Undefined as of C++23? How else to do it?
```

After line2, the array *itself* is [still alive](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1.5), because it [provides storage](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#3) to the T, which *is* [nested](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#4) within the array, but the array *elements* should now be out-of-lifetime, because their storage has been reused by the T, and T is not nested within them, only within the array *itself*.

However, how can we delete this array after we're done using it, using the pointer `foo`, which is a pointer to the out-of-lifetime first element?

Until (exluding) C++23 [[basic.life]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#6.1) suggested to allow, or at least didn't forbid, to use this pointer in the `delete` expression:

> The program has undefined behavior if:
> (6.1) the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor and the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression,

this does not apply to `unsigned char` at it's not a class type. However, starting in C++23 [this sentence was changed](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6.1) to

> The program has undefined behavior if: (6.1) the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression,

which now includes `unsigned char`.

Does this mean it's not supposed to be possible anymore to use a char-array as storage in this way?

My research into the standard has given me 3 possible interpratations so far:

1. it might have something to do with the "object representation" now being defined to be an array of unsigned chars, meaning that, potentially, the pointer has now come to point to a new unsigned char, part of the "object representation" and is therefore still alive, or
2. the entire [basic.life/6](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6) paragrah is not supposed to apply here given that it says:

> and before the storage which the object occupied is reused

which has happened, although this reuse has *also* ended again by calling `~T()`, or

3. could it even be possible that this was *never* supposed to work with arrays created with a `new`-expression considering that the `new`-expression does not allow us to specify the required alignment anyway?

Which of these, if any, might be correct?

Comment: Arguably the bullet you identify doesn't apply, because the paragraph above forbids doing any of the operations "before the storage is released", and `delete[] storage;` does release the storage, it is not ordered before the release of storage.

Comment: You could also, if you like, call placement new `new (storage) unsigned char[original_size];`, which sets everything back up perfectly for the automatic (trivial) destructor calls which occur during `delete[] storage;`  Now it's "un-reused" in a way that `p->~T()` does not satisfy.

Comment: Do you mean new-placing another `unsigned char[]` within the existing `unsigned char[]` just before calling `delete[]`? Interesting solution. I don't understand your first comment, however. Which operations that are in the snippet are forbidden before the release of the storage? Do you mean line 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes to first question (another `unsigned char[]`), although it isn't "within an existing" one. Then no, I meant that you are interpreting [basic.life]/6.1 to forbid passing the pointer as the operand of delete, but it doesn't forbid that unconditionally.  It forbids passing the pointer to delete in a particular interval, starting when the object lifetime has ended and ending when the storage is released.  `delete[] storage` *is* the end point (release of storage) of that interval.  [basic.life]/6 uses the word "before" which indicates that the interval is open and doesn't include its endpoint.

Comment: Can you plz https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues? (Broken by https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2625.html)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't feel confident in my assessment of the interpretations here right now i.e. whether this was ever intended at all, and I don't have a suggested resolution to put in that github issue. I believe you have opened a few issues there before, If you'd like, feel free to open a CWG issue about this, if you believe it's a defect.

Comment: @BenVoigt Interesting point about the “before” wording. However, I think if the same logic was applied to basic.life/8 “transparent placement”, it would break, because then the replacement-new would not happen “before” itself.